# Pandas data frame ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using `barchart` function taken from [here](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/plotting-graphs-with-python).

```
def barchart(x,y,x_title,y_title,numbins=10):
    datarange=max(x)-min(x)
    bin_width=float(datarange)/numbins
    pos=min(x)
    bins=[0 for i in range(numbins+1)]

    for i in range(numbins):
        bins[i]=pos
        pos+=bin_width
    bins[numbins]=max(x)+1
    binsum=[0 for i in range(numbins)]
    bincount=[0 for i in range(numbins)]
    binaverage=[0 for i in range(numbins)]

    for i in range(numbins):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            if x[j]>=bins[i] and x[j]<bins[i+1]:
                bincount[i]+=1
                binsum[i]+=y[j]

    for i in range(numbins):
        binaverage[i]=float(binsum[i])/bincount[i]
    barplot(range(numbins),binaverage,x_title,y_title)
```

I run this function in the following way (`df` is a pandas data frame):

```
barchart(df.DAY_OF_WEEK, df.WEATHER_DELAY, "WEATHER DELAY", "DAY", len(df.DAY_OF_WEEK.unique()))
```

The line `if x[j]>=bins[i] and x[j]<bins[i+1]:` gives this error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: what is the value of `df.DAY_OF_WEEK`? the error message makes it seem that `x[index]` is returning a Series, not a string/number/what youre expecting

Comment: @R Nar: df is pandas data frame. so, df.DAY_OF_WEEK is a series. in this case how can I make the code working?

Comment: It looks like the function expects numpy arrays. Try ``barchart(df.DAY_OF_WEEK.values, df.WEATHER_DELAY.values, ...)``

Comment: Also, indexing a series will return a series if there are duplicate indices.

Comment: @jakevdp, thats what i was trying to go for. it looks like the indexing is returning a series, not a specific value

Comment: @jakevdp: Adding .values solved the problem.